# PHP and MySQL and PayPal

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have a membership page where user can select plan and enter there information and when click on signup button then all entry should be in MySQL and its redirect to PayPal and payment should be same as user have selected and after payment it should redirect to thanks page and from there they can make login in his account.

My membership plan is of 5 type.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below link:

[Paypal Integration with PHP,MySQL](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-payment-system-with-paypal_249.html)